# How to define delayed coupon payment for FinancialBond?

Tags: finance

When the coupon calculation end date falls on a holiday, it is customary to delay the coupon payment to the next working day. E.g. a bond may have a monthly coupon calculation period of 2013 Jul 18 to 2013 Aug 18 (Sunday), the actual payment is delayed to 2013 Aug 19 (Mon). The price of the bond should depend on the actual payment date of Aug 19. How do I achieve this using `FinancialBond`?

Comment: The difficulty is that FinancialBond seems to assume the coupon payment date is the same with calculation end date. Another blocker is the rigid "CouponInterval" option that makes it impossible to have irregular intervals. For this reason I'm on the verge of giving up FinancialBond and go back to TimeValue ...

Comment: A simpler way to achieve this would be to calculate the bond price on Sunday, and then capitalize the price you've found using the 1-day interest rate. Anyway, I'm not sure if you can choose the coupon dates in the `FinancialBond` function; I think you can only set the coupon intervals...

Comment: But Sunday's price will be wrong to begin with because FinancialBond is not using the correct payment dates. I do not see why the parameters of FinancialBond cannot include a CashFlow object like TimeValue does.